# I have a dog with attributes, but tailLength and age need to change if I add 1 year to the dog, !the weight

Tags: java, class

I have a dog with some attributes input by the user, if 1 year is added to the dog, the age and tail length needs to change but the weight stays the same, there can only be six public methods in this assignment.

ex. `name = "Doggie"`, `Breed = "dogBreed"`, `age = 1`, `weight = 2`,
I can get the age to change `if getAge(1);` but still the tail remains the same and not even shown too be added, I dont know how to get it since its a double not an int, and also I get the `tailLenght` to be 0.0, this can be fixed if I change the `tailLenght = getAge(newAge) * dogWeight)` to `tailLenght = dogBirth * dogWeight;` but then I dont get the result I want from changing the age from 1 to 2. Idk what to do.

```
public class Dog {

    private String dogName;
    private String dogBreed;
    private int dogBirth;
    private double dogWeight;
    private double tailLenght;
    private int newAge;

    public Dog(String dogName, String dogBreed, int dogBirth, double dogWeight) {
        this.dogBirth = dogBirth;
        this.dogBreed = dogBreed;
        this.dogName = dogName;
        this.dogWeight = dogWeight;
    }

    // get name from DogTest
    public String getName() {
        return dogName;
    }

    // get breed from Dogtest
    public String getBreed() {
        return dogBreed;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return dogBirth;
    }

    // get weight from DogTest
    public double getWeight() {
        return dogWeight;
    }

    // New age if added years
    public int getAge(int years) {
        newAge = dogBirth + years;

        return newAge;

    }

    // Check tail Length
    public double getTailLength(double i) {

        if (dogBreed.equalsIgnoreCase("tax") || dogBreed.equalsIgnoreCase("dachshund")) {
            tailLenght = 3.7;
        } else {
            tailLenght = (getAge(newAge) * dogWeight) / 10f;
        }
        return tailLenght;
    }

    //Whats to be shown
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("name=%s breed=%s weight=%.1fkg age=%d taillenght=%.1" + "f", dogName, dogBreed, dogWeight,
                dogBirth, getTailLength(newAge));
    }

}
```

Comment: It's highly appreciated, that you would know the name of the language you're working with.

Comment: Please provide a piece of code when you use this class Dog.

Comment: Its an autoprogram that calls for the method getAge() and adds 1 which in turn is intended to change the age and the tailLenght, if I where to include a setAge() it cannot be a public method (because the program only permits 6 public methods including (and is also a demand) the getAge() method)

Comment: Ok, got it, i think... You have to set all the values in a parametrized constructor and only change (increase) the age afterwards, which should then automatically increase the tail length, right? There is something I don't understand, that is the method `getTailLength(double tailLength)`. Why do you *set* values there? Why don't you set them in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, the auto program sets all the values, and the age is increased afterwards by the program using the getAge() method which also automatically change the tail lenght, thats correct.
the program only increases the age by 1 as far as I know but it shouldnt matter

I am not sure If I understand but the value of the tail length is never given, it calculated by age * weight / 10

Comment: I really think nothing should be increased by a method that is called `getSomething` because that means you only get a value returned that was set before using another method or the constructor. Does the auto program really require this method?

Comment: Yes it requires it, but I think it only uses the method by adding 1 to getAge(int x)

Comment: Could you please post the original assignment? I really want to know what is going on there ;-)

Comment: One option is to store in your fields something like "tail length without age" and in your `getTailLength()` to calculate the correct value taking into account the age.

Comment: we.tl/t-6VU5jKOnxq this is just a picture of what is needed to be included, as public, private constants or methods is still possible, otherwise the assignment says that a new method is to be created for the age increase thats why I created the getAge(int), because when I did run the evaluate the program called for the getAge(int) method ... and also the calc for tail length which is age*weight/10. I could post the text* but its in swedish so if u cant read it idk.

Comment: @Markus I have seen this question, obviously posted by a fellow student of yours and it has 8 (!) answers, finding out why is up to you ;-) See [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124934/how-to-make-a-method-to-update-attributes-of-a-class#54125019).

Comment: Hahaha! yes indeed it is one of my classmates! and it worked Thank you deHaar! very cool!